# In canvas, how to draw 2 semi-transparent overlapping circles

Tags: html, canvas

I want to draw two circles on the gray rectangle in HTML canvas.

I attempted the following steps:

1. Fill rectangle gray
2. Change `globalComposition` lighter to mix two colors.

I want to mix only blue and red, not gray and gray rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this property by fill style of the circles in `rgba`, where the last parameter will be alpha or opacity. The syntax will be something like this

```
circle.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
//can be used to fill as red object with opacity of 0.5
```

The complete code to achieve the desired effect will be something like this.

```js
 // JavaScript Code

 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var centerleftX = canvas.width / 4;
 var centerRightX = 3 * canvas.width / 4;
 var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
 var radius = 70;

 context.beginPath();
 context.rect(0, 0, 400, 200);
 context.fillStyle = 'rgb(200,200,200)';
 context.fill();
 context.lineWidth = 7;
 context.strokeStyle = 'black';
 context.stroke();


 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(centerleftX + 50, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0,255,0.7)";
 context.fill();


 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(centerRightX - 50, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0,0,0.7)";
 context.fill();
```

```html
 
 <!-- HTML Code -->
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200">
```